# Outlook 2010 meeting Requests forwarding to another user

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010, meeting-request

Whenever a meeting request is sent to User A (using Outlook 2010) not meeting request also forwards to User B (also using Outlook 2010). I have looked at delegate settings, outlook rules, mail flow settings and quite a few pages on Google search results. I'm hoping that maybe someone here is an exchange wizard. Gracias.

Comment: This only happens with a single user or multiple users?  You sure this isn't on the user's end?

Comment: This only happens with the one user in our network. Only User A's requests go to User B. No one else is affected. I've looked through his outlook but cant find anything. I did see that his calendar permissions for 'default' was set to owner, but i changed that back to reviewer and it still forwarded the meeting. The user leaves in an hour so I'll be back at it, anything i should try outside of reinstall?